# Binding source not updating when DependencyProperty's value is set to null

Tags: c#, uwp, binding

I have a custom UserControl. It is composed of a TextBox and a Button. The objective of this user control is to allow the user to see the ToString() content of an object, which is set in the XAML via Binding and also allow them to set the object to NULL.
This is the XAML and C# code of the UserControl

```
<UserControl
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Text="{x:Bind SelectedObject.ToString(), Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <Button Click="buttonDeselectObject_Click" IsEnabled="True" Content="X"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

```
public sealed partial class ObjectSelectorBox : UserControl 
{
    public ObjectSelectorBox ()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent ();

        textBoxSelectedObject.AddHandler (TappedEvent, new TappedEventHandler (TextBox_Tapped), true);
    }

    public object SelectedObject 
    {
        get => GetValue (SelectedObjectProperty);
        set => SetValue (SelectedObjectProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedObjectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register ("SelectedObject", typeof (object), typeof (ObjectSelectorBox), null);

    private void buttonDeselectObject_Click (object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        //This is where the SelectedObject binding source should be set to NULL

        SelectedObject = null; //This works but does NOT reflect to the binding source
        SelectedObject = "123"; //This works and does reflect to the binding source
    }
}
```

This is how I use it in a UWP Page:

```
<local1:ObjectSelectorBox SelectedObject="{x:Bind TestObject, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

When the user presses the button the SelectedObject value should be set null. While this does work, the change does not reflect to the binding source which is TestObject (string).
However when I set SelectedObject value to something else like "123" or "abc" the change is correctly reflected to TestObject.
Is this behaviour intentional and is there a way to change it so changed to SelectedObject always reflect to the binding source?

Comment: Your binding is trying to call .ToString() on a null object, then it fails.

Comment: Oh. Wow. I didn't realize that. I have to accustomed to exceptions raising and Visual Studio spoon-feeding me. Sigh. Thank you very much anyways :D

Answer (score 0):

> Binding source not updating when DependencyProperty's value is set to null

Iuri Farenzena's comment is correct, it fails when call `ToString()` with null object. Why we can't get exception within Visual Studio. Because the exception has captured internally and stop reflecting to the binding source.

For your requirement, please use `string.Empty` to replace null.

```
SelectedObject = string.Empty
```

**Update**

**Op's solution**

Implementing a custom `IValueConverter`  and use `value?.ToString()` to determine if the value is null.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying. I ended up implementing a custom IValueConverter which does _value_?.ToString().